# Modifying cumulative sum with values from a second field

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, zoo

This is what my dataframe looks like. `NewCumV1` is my desired field.

library(data.table)
dt <- fread('

```
        V1     V2    NewCumV1  Group V3
        1       1     2          1   1
        0       2     4          1   1
        0       4     8          1   1
        0       3     11         1   2
        2       1     16         2   1
        0       2     18         2   2
        0       5     23         2   3
        1       2     29         3   1    ')
```

`NewCumV1` is just `cumsum(V1+V2)`generally and `cumsum(V1+V2)+Last Value of V3 from prior group` for rows when the group changes.

So in the 5th row, when Group changes from `Group=1` to `Group=2`, I take the existing `cumsum` which is  11 and add `2=V1` and `1=V2` and `2=V3` ,which is last value of V3 from prior `Group=1`,to it.So,

```
NewCumV1 For New Group2 at 5th row= 11+2+1+2 = 16
```

After that, it is regular `cumsum(V1+V2)` again  until the `Group` changes. So from the 6th row the calculation should be:

```
16+0+2=18(6th row)
18+0+5=23(7th row)
```

8th row is a new group where `Group=3`, so there is a `cumsum` reset. I take the `NewCumV1` from the last group which is 23 and add `V1=1` and `V2=2`  and `V3=3` to it.So,

```
23+1+2+3=29(last row)
```

I have tried:

```
dt[NewCumV1:= cumsum(V1+V2)+ last(V3), by=Group))]
```

Comment: For the last value in NewCumV1, is that correct?  if you calculate `cumsum(V2)` for each 'Group', the 7th observation value is 8, so I get 31 instead of 23

Comment: If the above comment is right, then `dt[, New1 := cumsum(V2), Group][, i1 := shift((!duplicated(Group, fromLast=TRUE))*New1, fill=0)][Group!=1, New1 := cumsum(i1+V1+V2)][, i1:= NULL][]`

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your great answer. This small change `dt[Group!=1, New1 := cumsum(i1+V1+V2), by=Group]` at the end of your code gets my job done. I will do some edits in my post to make it clear.

Comment: @akrun Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I posted with the modification you mentioned, but still I am not gettng the 23 for the last value

Comment: @akrun You are right.  I swear I saw 23. Must have been hallucinating. Do you see a fault with my thought process in the post? I updated the post but cant quite catch the hole in my thinking.

Comment: The problem I find is that in the Group 2, you added 10+2+1, while in Group 3, shouldn't it be 8 + 1 + 2 i.e. `dt[, cumsum(V2), Group]$V1
#[1]  1  3  7 10  1  3  8  2`

Comment: @akrun I updated the post. I hope it has more logical consistency.

Comment: @well, thats not right. One can just do cumsum(V1+V2). will change it.

Comment: @akrun I changed the post, hopefully for the last time. I can get a lot done with the help you already provided me. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this IIUW:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('

            V1     V2    NewCumV1  Group
            1       1     1          1
            0       2     3          1
            0       4     7          1
            0       3     10         1
            2       1     13         2
            0       2     15         2
            0       5     20         2
            1       2     23         3 ')

dt[Group == 1, cus := cumsum(V2)]
dt[Group != 1, cus := cumsum(V2+V1), by = Group]
foo <- dt[, .(addons = cus[.N]), by = Group]
foo[, `:=`(addons = cumsum(addons), Group = Group + 1)]
dt <- merge(dt, foo[1:(nrow(foo)-1)], by = "Group", all = T)
dt[, cus := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = T), .SDcols = c("cus", "addons")]
#    Group V1 V2 NewCumV1 cus addons
# 1:     1  1  1        1   1     NA
# 2:     1  0  2        3   3     NA
# 3:     1  0  4        7   7     NA
# 4:     1  0  3       10  10     NA
# 5:     2  2  1       13  13     10
# 6:     2  0  2       15  15     10
# 7:     2  0  5       20  20     10
# 8:     3  1  2       23  23     20
```